# Get count of rows from multiple tables Redshift SQL?

Tags: sql, r, count, rows

I have a redshift database that is being updated with new tables so I can't just manually list the tables I want. I want to get a count of the rows of all the tables from my query. So far I have:

```
select 'SELECT ''' || table_name || ''' as table_name, count(*) As con ' ||
       'FROM ' || table_name || 
        CASE WHEN lead(table_name) OVER (order by table_name ) IS NOT NULL 
        THEN ' UNION ALL ' END
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%results%'
```

but when I do this I get the error:

```
Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

I've searched a lot but I can't seem to find a solution for my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I've changed my approach to this and decided to use a for loop in R to get the row counts of each but I'm running into the issue that 'row_counts' is only saving one number, not the count of each row like I want. Here is the code:

```
schema <- "x"
table_prefix <- "results"
geos <- ad_districts %>% filter(geo != "geo")
row_count <- list()
i = 1

for (geo in geos){
  table_name <- paste0(schema, ".", table_prefix, geo)
  row_count[[i]] <- dbGetQuery(con, 
                             paste("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM", table_name))
  i = i + 1 
}
```

Comment: *I have a redshift database that is being updated with new tables so I can't just manually list the tables I want* ... this is not a well-designed database. All structural DB objects should be developed **once** during design stage and intact thereafter. No schemas, tables, columns, users should be dynamically built on the fly. All should be manually run DDL processes.

Comment: Your tables may be run at application layer: Java, C#, Ruby, Perl, PHP, Python, R. Be careful with runaway scripts as you can run two lines that build 10,000 tables! Relational databases are NOT spreadsheets. Explain more your entire process as you might not need all those many tables.

Comment: It is not possible to construct a Redshift query where the table name is the result of a sub-query. You will need to run it in two passes -- one to retrieve a list of table names, and then separate queries to count rows in a table.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] - I think this is the root cause - some sql functions are only supported on the leader node. Try connecting to that node and re-run your SQL.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_sql-functions-leader-node.html

Hope this helps.

```
select 'select count(*) as "' || table_schema || '.' || table_name || '" from ' || table_schema || '.' || table_name || ' ;' as sql_text
from information_schema.tables
;
```

[EDIT - refined this a bit to generate a series of statements that can be run at once]

```
select rownum, case when rownum > 1 then sql_text else replace(sql_text, 'union all', '') end as sql_text
from
(
select rank() over (order by sql_text DESC) as rownum,
        sql_text
from
(
select 'select ''' || table_schema || ' ' || table_name || ''' , count(*) as "' || table_schema || '.' || table_name || '" from ' || table_schema || '.' || table_name || ' union all ' as sql_text
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public'
order by table_schema, table_name
)X
)Y 
order by rownum desc ;
```

Comment: the first worked to create the statements but the second gave an error. how do I make a query to actually get the counts based off this query results?

Comment: What was the error? I should have mentioned I was running this in Postgres with PGAdmin, but Redshift and Postgres share the same engine.

Comment: the same error in the my original question: "Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables."

Comment: what would the next step be for the first part? I'm trying to use it as a subquery but I can't get it to work.

Comment: How are you interacting with Redshift? SQL Workbench, or some other end-user SQL interface?

Comment: I believe you need to connect only to the leader node, as not all sql functions are supported by the other nodes. Edited this into the top portion of my answer.

Comment: I was using R to access it

Answer (score 0):

Your query is doing a select * for all tables, this will take a lot of time and resources. Instead use a system table to get the same info

```
select name, sum(rows) as rows
from stv_tbl_perm
where name like '%results%'
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ' Select count(*) , '''+ tablename + '''  from   '+'"' + tablename +'"' +'  Union ALL  '
FROM pg_table_def
GROUP BY tablename
```

Above query eliminates any table name with space. Remove UNION ALL at the end of the query and query will be ready to be executed.